# Connect to MS SQL server from PL/SQL Developer

Tags: sql-server, plsqldeveloper

I have PL/SQL Developer installed on my machine.
Version:-7.1.2

I want to connect to MS sql server from PL/SQL Developer. I have SQL server address, username and password with me.

I tried to search for the solution every possible way.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: PL/SQL Developer can only talk/connect to an Oracle database.

Comment: What is your exact problem? What is the error message you got? What did you try? (Does SQL Server mean Microsoft SQL Server? Which version?)

Comment: I have installed PLSQL Developer by allround automations. On their site it is mention it supports the SQL server. http://www.orafaq.com/tools/allround/developer.htm

Comment: There is only one line which mentions SQL Server: `Rapid SQL - Embarcadero ( Got a good Orafaq review ). Has the advantage of supporting SQL Server, DB2 and Sybase in addition to Oracle.` This line is in the `Competitive products` section.

Comment: TOAD might be a choice if you want to do pl-sql and sql server, it comes in different flavors.

Comment: OraFAQ isn't their site anyway. You want http://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html (which only mentions Oracle).

Comment: You can't. Just install SQL Server Management Studio - it's free

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Directly from [their web page](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) (emphasis mine):

> PL/SQL Developer is an Integrated Development Environment that is **specifically targeted** at the development of stored program units for **Oracle Databases**.

To connect to MS SQL Server from your desktop you need [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) (free), [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download?view=sql-server-2017) (free), [Toad for SQL Server](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/) ($$$), or another client that advertises connectivity to SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

1. open sql server from server objects add a linked servers to oracle
2. add stored procedure that will insert into the table in oracle and reads from sql table.
   example:

   ```
   INSERT INTO OPENQUERY (ERPTEST, 'SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEE')
   select Employee_Number,Full_Name_1 from [EmpDB].[dbo].[EMPLOYEES];
   ```